# Inter-rater reliability: two raters rate dataset A and two raters rate dataset B how to combine it into one number?

Tags: reliability, agreement-statistics

Me and one other person (Alice) counted the amount of boys and girls playing on a school playground (consent of parents and school were given of it being videotaped). Two other persons (Bob and Claire) counted the amount of boys and girls playing on another school playground. After every 30 seconds we would pause the video and count the amount of boys and girls. So now we have 2 playgrounds, one is rated by me and Alice and the other one is rated by Bob and Claire.

The data kind of looks like this:

```
Note: the suffix is the first letter of the person who counted.

Playground 1 (rated by Me and Alice)
Time    BoysM   GirlsM  BoysA   GirlsA
00:00   5       4       4       4
00:30   4       6       4       6
01:00   7       5       5       5

Playground 2 (rated by Bob and Claire)
Time    BoysB   GirlsB  BoysC   GirlsC
00:00   1       8       1       6
00:30   3       8       3       6
01:00   2       8       2       6
```

Would I have serious issues if I assume there to be two raters who rated the playgrounds and just go from there? I just combine the data of Alice with Claire and my data with Bob. It would make it easier for me to find out what type of interrater reliability I'd have to calculate.

If that is a big issue, how would I go about it? Is there some type of inter-rater that I could still calculate? Is there some way to account for this?

Comment: [Intraclass correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation) may be useful

Answer (score 1):

Here is my tentative answer that I have currently. When I read the paper called:  [Agreement Between Two Independent Groups Of Raters written by Sophie Vanbelle and Adelin Alber](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11336-009-9116-1#page-1) (note: behind a paywall), I get the idea that independent raters that do not share any single rated instance together should be viewed as two different entities. They do not say this, but the authors note that there's almost no theory on independent rater groups that *do* have shared rated instances of data together.

So I'm left with the choice of displaying two values and leave it at that or average them out (i.e. divide it by 2). The choice will hinge on brevity versus comprehensiveness.